# SQLite android programming issue

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

MY program is note working on the emulator.  There are no errors in the code from eclipse.  It says that "the process has stopped unexpectedly".  I have tried to run the xml code by it self and it comes up without a problem.  I also have a db file of the same activity however I am more suspicious of this file being the cause of the problem.  I cannot find any thing to help find the answer.  I do not know much about programming but I have been researching this application.  The solution to this would help many people who might have this problem or are interested in this activity.

I am interested in inserting a fixed text from a button into a database.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Watchnotes extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity, menu);
        return true;
    }



    // public interface
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        boolean didItWork = true;
        try{

            switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:

            String note = "XXXX";

            NAME entry = new NAMEdb(NAME.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(note);
            entry.close();}
            }catch (Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
            }finally{
                if (didItWork){
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("XXXX");
            d.show();}


            }

    }


    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (((View) arg0).getId()){
            case R.id.button5:
                Intent i = new Intent("com.intent.LIST");
                startActivity(i);}}}
```

Comment: You need to initialize your button; like so: button1 = (Button) findviewById(R.id.button1); Add it to your onCreate method before you set the onClick listener.

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem. Just initialize

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main3);
    addListenerOnButton1();
    addListenerOnButton2();

}
public void addListenerOnButton1() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }


    });
```